# Timeout parameter of Python Requests causing exception

Tags: python, python-requests

I have some Requests code that is meant to allow my code to retry a URL a set number of times after a set length of time before time out:

```
import requests

s = Session()
s.mount('http://www.example.com/', HTTPAdapter(
max_retries=Retry(total=50, status_forcelist=
[400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418,
421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 428, 429, 431, 451, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505, 506, 507, 508, 510, 511])
)
)

url = 'www.example.com/somepage'

params = {'param1': '1', 'param2': '2'}

headers = {'someheader': 'header'}

response = s.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=60)
```

However this is causing the below error, which I am unsure of the reason for. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ExampleScript.py", line 244, in examplefunction
    response = s.get(url, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=60)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 468, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 456, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 559, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 327, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 558, in urlopen
    "broken by '%r': %s" % (retries, err, url))
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not Retry
```

Thanks

Comment: `max_retries` should be an int

Comment: @PadraicCunningham hello again. i think i might have overcomplicated things a bit...im trying 's.mount('http://www.whoscored.com/', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=50))' now instead.

Comment: Hi, yes the max_retries goes in the HTTPAdapter constructor, does that not work?

Comment: just trying it now. i had this code commented out for ages, but ive added it back in as ive been having some issues with connection requests stalling and throwing up errors when raised programatically...will have to see what happens. im not sure from this code though that will know a retry has happened will i?

Comment: Bar sticking a print in the source I don't think you can with requests, you can try `import httplib;httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1` to see if you get more info

Comment: when you see use a print, what object from the requests module would you print to see the retry count? my thinking is it would be good to see how many retrys there had been at the end of the job run

Comment: I imagines https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py, I also see there is some logging there when there is a retry so you coud use that

Comment: ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: No worries, it is  `requests.packages.urllib3.add_stderr_logger()`

Comment: The example in the docs also uses  `s.mount('http://'...`, not sure if it makes a difference or not.